# Device GPS acting strange - unpredictable results

Tags: android, gps

In my program I track position using GPS receiver and send to my server. Getting some weird results from *some* devices. Out of 200+ devices 1 or 2 like this. Consider last couple pings:

[image]

And this looks like so on map:

[image]

I would understand if Accuracy reported was bad. But it looks ok - 52 meters is not 200+ miles..

Does anybody have any ide on why this might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the altitude figures are garbage, I would guess that this is a case of flaky hardware.

Comment: Yes, I also see junk altitude values. I wonder if there is acceptable range so I can at least implement filtering around it?

Comment: @katit: Well, in terms of altitude, I would think that positive numbers (or at least not too negative) would be a starting point. Few of your users will be located 1000km below the Earth's surface, unless your app is popular among the Mole Men. :-)